# Piping into results of another pipe not working as expected

Tags: bash, ssh, pipe

I am a newbie in bash programming and was playing around with some commands trying to learn how passing multiple arguments using pipeline and grouping commands work when I faced this odd behavior which confused me a lot.
I know other ways to achieve the what I want, however, I am trying to understand why this is happening.

I am trying to send a message to a user (let's consider their user ID as USER and their TTY as TTY) connected to my SSH server, using the `write`
<s>builtin function</s> program.

While I was able to send the message just fine using the following command:

`$ echo "some message" | write USER TTY`

But when I was trying to pass USER and TTY using another pipeline,
the message was not being sent:

`$ echo "some message" | { echo "USER TTY" | xargs -o write; }`

In the results, it seems the bash ignores the first part (`$ echo "some message"`), and need to enter the message after execution of the command.

Note that `{ echo "USER TTY" | xargs -o write; }` and `write USER TTY` does the same job (apparently? I suspect there is a difference here that I am not aware of).

Again, I know that there are much easier ways to do this, but I just am trying to understand how bash works regarding grouping commands, piping, and passing input arguments to a function. Any comments on these areas are extremely appreciated.

---

For those who suspect I am asking this for a homework, which is nice to see people caring about these stuff, I genuinely was trying to create an alias that sends a message to every user on my ssh server, which I found `wall` does it way easier, though found it interesting to figure what I mentioned here out.

Comment: Please be honest, is this a homework or assignment question?

Comment: @ilkkachu Thank you for taking your time reading my question. You are very correct, I spent a whole day trying to find out a way to pass two arguments using pipeline without xargs, i.e. ```echo " source destination | mv``` but was not successful. As mentioned, I am very newbie to this area. However, I believe they do same job if you run these two commands

Comment: @SeetheMoar I am a neuroengineer interested in bash programming, you can simply search my name. BTW, I believe even if it was some sort of homework, the question still is valid since first of all I am asking how it works, ( and as I mentioned I know some other ways to achieve what I want), and second, others can learn too.

Comment: To be blunt, if you start from a misconception like “`Command B | Command C` does the same job as `Command D`” (which you could have easily checked, in isolation, without introducing `Command A`), and then you pile a complicated question on top of the initial misconception, and then you change the question halfway through (pulling `xargs` out of a hat), and you give it a title that’s down in the weeds of your example, rather than describing your question (such as it is), then nobody else is going to learn anything from it.

Comment: @G-ManSays'ReinstateMonica' Well I guess regarding these two doing the same job I mentioned that "apparently? I suspect there is a difference here that I am not aware of". and also as I mentioned, as a newbie, when I run these two commands they do the same job. But you are totally correct about xargs, and also I agree I should have been more clear (possible should ask multiple questions instead of one, but you can see this is my first question here), but let me disagree on your final point "nobody else is going to learn from it". anyways, I was just trying to prove it is not for "homework".

Comment: @MohammadBadriAhmadi, the first part of your question quite literally says _"where Command B | Command C does the same job as Command D"_, with nothing there hinting any sort of doubt. But they don't do the same thing. Basing a question on a false premise rather makes it appear quite sloppy at best, and might not exactly help in getting a good answer. Neither does having the situation change in the middle of the post.

Comment: @ilkkachu You're right. Now that G-Man addressed my mistakes, I understand why my question had a lot of problems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your

```
echo "some message" | { echo "USER TTY" | xargs -o write; }
```

command can’t work because it does this:

```
                        |-------------------------------------------|
echo "some message"   --+->   echo "USER TTY"  -->  xargs -o write; |
                        |-------------------------------------------|
```

The standard input of the `xargs` is the pipe from `echo "USER TTY"`. 
The `echo "some message"` gets piped into the compound command
`{ echo "USER TTY" | xargs -o write; }`,
which, practically, means that
the `echo "some message"` gets piped into the `echo "USER TTY"`;
which means that the `write` command cannot see the `some message`. 
P.S. Since you have specified
the `-o` option to `xargs`, `write`’s standard input is set to the terminal. 
This would work if you wanted to say

```
echo "USER TTY" | xargs -o write
```

and then just type the message,
but it doesn’t connect `write` to the outermost `echo`.

If you have some *`Command B`* that outputs *`USER`* and *`TTY`*
(but just one pair),
you could try

```
echo "some message" | write $(Command B)
```

**Update:** The below may work in the hypothetical case
where *`Command B`* outputs just one pair of *`USER`* and *`TTY`*,
but probably won’t work for your actual situation. 
Read it, but then see the discussion further down.

> If, as you say, you’re using bash, and you have GNU `xargs`
> (standard on Linux; probably available for other Unix-like operating systems)
> you could also try

```
echo "some message" | xargs -a <(Command B) write
```

as suggested by rici in
[Reading in from stdin from a command executed with xargs](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19961319/3960947#19963123).

I just realized that you probably have GNU `xargs`,
because the `-o` option isn’t specified by POSIX.

---

More thoughts:

- This may address part of your question: 
  Offhand, I cannot think of any example where

  ```
  Command A | { Command B | Command C; }
  ```

  is different from

  ```
  Command A | Command B | Command C
  ```

  i.e.,
  where the grouping makes a difference. 
  I expect that I am overlooking something obvious,
  and I look forward to having an example pointed out to me. 
  Likewise,

  ```
  { Command A | Command B; } | Command C
  ```

  would be equivalent.
- Pipelines like

  ```
  Command A | Command B | Command C
  ```

  can be useful. 
  As a trivial example:

  ```
  $ echo GET | tr BEG VAC | od -cb
  0000000   C   A   T  \n
          103 101 124 012
  0000004
  ```
- A pipeline like

  ```
  Command A | Command B | xargs (options)  Command Y
  ```

  can be useful if you are thinking of it as

  ```
  { Command A | Command B; }  |  xargs (options)  Command Y
  ```

  i.e., `Command A | Command B` provides the input to `xargs`. 
  If you’re thinking of it as

  ```
  Command A  |  { Command B | xargs (options)  Command Y; }
  ```

  i.e., `Command B` provides the input to `xargs` and `Command A` provides the input to `Command Y`, it’s not going to work for the reason discussed above: there’s no way to establish a data flow between `Command A` and `Command Y`.
- However,

  ```
  Command A  |  xargs (options)  -a <(Command B)  Command Y
  ```

  is problematic for a different reason: the job of `xargs` here is to run `Command Y` (potentially) multiple times. 
  But there’s no mechanism to run `Command A` multiple times,
  so it cannot provide the input to `Command Y` multiple times.

  If you really want to run `Command A | Command Y` multiple times, you can do that with

  ```
  Command B | xargs (options)  sh -c 'Command A | Command Y' sh
  ```

  For example,

  ```
  $ echo S F u o n b | xargs -n2 sh -c 'date | tr "$1" "$2"; sleep 2' sh
  Fun, Mar 27, 2022 11:11:07 AM
  Son, Mar 27, 2022 11:11:09 AM
  Sub, Mar 27, 2022 11:11:11 AM
  ```

  This runs

  ```
  date | tr S F
  date | tr u o
  date | tr n b
  ```

  You can see that it is actually running `date` three times from the fact
  that the seconds are different (`07`, `09` and `11`).

  And this will work for your case. 
  (Note that, in my example above, `Command Y`
  takes arguments from `Command B` two at a time,
  like what you really want/need to do with `write`.) 
  If `Command B` produces output that looks like
  `name1 tty1 name2 tty2 name3 tty3 …`
  (e.g., `fred tty17 wilma tty42 barney ttyS23`), then you can do

  ```
  Command B | xargs -n2 (maybe other options)  sh -c 'echo "some message" | write "$1" "$2"' sh
  ```
- But, if you don’t need to run `Command A` (in your case, `echo "some message"`) multiple times (because it produces the same output every time), you could make use of that fact, and run `Command A` once, saving the output:

  ```
  echo "some message" > tmpfile; \
          Command B | xargs -n2 (maybe other options)  sh -c 'write "$1" "$2" < tmpfile' sh; \
          rm tmpfile
  ```
- So, the above solution avoids running `Command A` multiple times, but it still runs the shell once for each user. 
  This is undesirable. 
  I don’t see any way to handle this scenario,
  with `xargs`, without firing up the shell multiple times. 
  (Again, I anticipate having one pointed out to me.) 
  It’s hard to handle it without using the shell *at all,*
  because `xargs` can handle only ‘‘simple’’ commands
  — no redirections (`<`) or pipes (`|`). 
  ***But**,* we can handle it without `xargs`,
  using the shell more creatively. 
  Assuming that `Command B` produces output with one `namen ttyn` pair per line (e.g., `fred tty17` *(newline)* `wilma tty42` *(newline)* `barney ttyS23` *(newline)* ), then you can do

  ```
  echo "some message" > tmpfile; \
                Command B | while read u t; do write "$u" "$t" < tmpfile; done; \
                rm tmpfile
  ```

---

To get down into the weeds
and address a couple of micro-points from the question:

- In

  ```
  echo "some message" | { echo "USER TTY" | xargs -o write; }
  ```

  the shell isn’t actually ignoring
  the `echo "some message"` part, *per se.* 
  But, as I described in the first part of my answer,
  it is effectively piping it
  into the `echo "USER TTY"`part. 
  And `echo` doesn’t read its standard input;
  therefore, the *`message`* isn’t processed.
- > Note that `{ echo "USER TTY" | xargs -o write; }` and `write USER TTY`  do the same job (apparently? I suspect there is a difference here that I am not aware of).

  OK, in case this isn’t clear yet:
  both variants invoke the `write` program
  with arguments *`USER`* and *`TTY`*. 
  `write USER TTY` is a simple command
  that doesn’t modify its standard I/O streams,
  but simply reads from the existing stdin. 
  This could be the tty, or a pipe, or a file. 
  The `xargs` variant redirects `write`’s stdin to be `/dev/tty`,
  because that’s what `-o` does. 
  Normally (if you don’t specify `-a`), `xargs`’s stdin
  is the source of the arguments for the command to be executed,
  and so `xargs` doesn’t have access
  to the prevailing stdin in the larger environment
  (which would be the source of the *message* for `write`)
  — and therefore it cannot make *that* data stream
  available to the executed program. 
  So, if you don’t specify `-a` or `-o`, 
  `xargs` sets the stdin of the executed program to `/dev/null`.
- Note that

  ```
  command B | xargs -n2 -o write
  ```

  would sort-of work,
  but it would require you to type the input *message* once for each user,
  because it invokes `write` once for each user
  without having any way to save the message between iterations. 
  You *could* theoretically use this if you wanted to send different messages to different users, but it wouldn’t be practical,
  because it wouldn’t give you any prompts or feedback
  to tell you which user you were talking to.

Comment: First of all, Thank you so much for your detailed answer. Second, you are totally correct about the first part ( and second part as well), I should have mentioned it in the question. The problem is, I tried a lot to find ```Command A``` and ```Command B``` in a way that ```Command A | Command B``` becomes the same as ```write USER TTY```. However, I was not able to do it without using xargs. Regarding the last part of your answer, I totally understand it where I made a mistake now thanks to your explanation, however, do you think it is possible to do what I was trying ?

Comment: Also, I am sorry for not being able to vote to your answer, I am new here. However, what I meant by "what I was trying" is, basically piping ```echo "some message``` into the final result of ```echo "USER TTY" | xargs -o write```, similar to ```echo "some message" | write USER TTY```

Comment: @MohammadBadriAhmadi if you tell us in your question what you're trying achieve then we're likely to be able to provide a solution. Step away from generalities - they're great up to a point but from there on you need to talk specifics (if you can). It might be worth accepting one of these answers and then opening a new question that builds on what you have here but tells about the specific

Comment: G-man:Thank you so much for taking time to answer my question. Again, sorry for being so scattered, I am new and it is hard to know what I do not know in this area. @roamia you're very correct. I almost got all I need. The question is, as G-man said, very artificial, I just wanted to know how bash works regarding piping in general.

Comment: If you liked that,  here — have some more.

Comment: @G-ManSays'ReinstateMonica' I even cannot express how thankful I am. You cannot imagine how much easier you made it for me. I've been looking for this information for a long time and I would have. Cheers man.

Answer (score -1):

### First Point

- You cannot use `echo "<command arguments>" | command` because you're
  echoing arguments as input. If you want to use input for command
  arguments, you have to use xargs as a "translator" for converting
  input into command line arguments.

`xargs` is an external binary which is not part of the shell(i.e. bash). There are many versions of xargs but the version with the `-o` flag is found in the GNU userspace. Generally, on linux, you can use `man <command name>` to find out documentation about a particular command. From a [web version](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/xargs.1.html#DESCRIPTION) of the manual:

> This manual page documents the GNU version xargs.  xargs reads
> items from the standard input, delimited by **blanks** (*which can be
> protected with double or single quotes or a backslash*) or
> **newlines**, and executes the command (default is echo) one or more
> times with any initial-arguments followed by items read from
> standard input.

What xargs does is, it breaks the inputs into fields, think of a row in a table. For each field, (by default) xargs passes an argument to the program until a system defined limit is reached. Think of spaces and newlines as the separator, i.e. the `|` in a table. Since your input "USER TTY" has a space between USER and TTY, xargs creates something similar to a table row like so

| ARG1 | ARG2 |
| --- | --- |
| USER | TTY |

### Second Point

- If you want to pipe a file everytime a command is run, use xargs to
  pipe a file to the run command like so. Beware that this opens a new
  shell however, so environment variables from your current session
  cannot be used.

```
echo "USER TTY" | xargs -I REPL sh -c 'echo "some message" | write REPL'
```

Breakdown:
`-I` flag takes an argument `REPL` that is replaced by the field when the command is run.

|  |  |
| --- | --- |
| USER | TTY |

Therefore xargs will run

```
sh -c 'echo "some message" | write USER TTY'
```

Comment: "For each field, the given command is executed once.", no this would only apply with `xargs -n 1`. But it does split the input string `USER TTY` to the two arguments `USER` and `TTY`, and you're right it does interpret quotes itself (which actually makes it harder to use safely), so the input `"USER TTY"` (or a variant) would result in the single argument `USER TTY`. But we probably don't want that with `write`.

Comment: @SeeTheMoad I believe you made a mistake regarding xargs, as far as I know ( again, a newbie) it splits the string into input variables. and also, can you explain more about circumvent you mentioned? cause I piped all three cases you mentioned to ```write``` and none worked.

Comment: @ikkachu explained it way better than me

Comment: @MohammadBadriAhmadi See GMAN's answer first, it mentions your first mistake. You can't pipe command line arguments to a program as input. You must use xargs to translate piped input into command line arguments

Comment: @SeetheMoar: I appreciate being given credit, but I’m not sure I like you mentioning my name.  Your answer “adds to” mine like dropping a football on the dinner table adds to the meal.  And I was going to say what ilkkachu said, but they beat me to it.

Comment: @G-ManSays'ReinstateMonica' I made the mistake of using printf for testing xargs so I did the whole xargs table row thing for explaining what I thought was another mistake in OP's methods. I have edited it to answer the OP's comment under your post as to how to echo "some thing" to the command run by xargs. I apologize for the inconvenience caused.

Comment: I can understand your response way better now. Appreciate it